# Custom Spring Scope not working for Message Channel

Tags: java, spring, message-queue, spring-integration

In spring integration, I am trying to create a Direct Message channel with a custom scope as follows

```
  ...
  <int:channel id="myChannel" scope="validCustomScope" />
  <int:service-activator ref="validSericeReference_WithSameValidCustomScope" method="handleMessage" input-channel="myChannel"/>
  ...
```

However, I am running into an exception ..

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel
```

Note: this custom scope works for other beans.
This issue is similar to what is discussed [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/118824-is-it-possible-to-give-a-custom-scope-to-a-direct-channel-no-subscriber-issue), but to no resolution. If someone can help resolve this issue, it will be a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

The service activator will only get subscribed to one of the instances. The others will throw `Dispatcher has no subscribers`.

Your custom scope would need to figure out how to propagate the subscription (service activator's `MessageHandler`) for every instance when the service activator is `start()` ed, and then propagate it to any new instances created `after` the endpoint was started.

Non-trivial probably.

That said. the benefit of a scoped channel sending messages to a non-scoped service is not clear to me.

Perhaps if you explain what you are trying to do with the custom scope there might be a general solution, but my guess it will need some tricky code in the custom scope.

Comment: Thanks Gary -- We want a scoped channel to send message only to *exactly the same* scoped service. Is there a way to force it?

Comment: Yes; create a separate child context (with channel, service) and use a dynamic router to route to the appropriate channel. See the dynamic FTP sample for an example of how to do that. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp

Comment: Thanks for the sample reference. Can service activators not subscribe to the same scoped channels? This would be a more natural configuration than trying to write code to dynamically route messages at runtime. Can <aop:scoped-proxy/> help in some way? We even tried using Thread scope for channel as specified in "Scoped Channel" section of http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html but resulting in the same "Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel" exception.

Comment: No, the framework's just not set up to understand scoped channels at that level. The channel subscriber wiring happens when the consumer is started by the application context. By their very nature, scoped channels can come and go after the context has been started. The `ThreadLocal` scope in the doc is a special case and will only work with a `QueueChannel`. In your custom scope, you could subscribe a new handler. Have your handler implement `MessageHandler` and declare it in your custom scope - get a new handler instance from the context and subscribe it when you create a new channel.

Comment: Thanks Gary -- We are proceeding with the Router option. However, is it possible to open a ticket in Spring Integration to allow in future, same Scoped Channels and Services to be @autowired without this overhead of  having this router to detect right service? There is a huge advantage of being able to do that. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, feel free to open a 'new feature' JIRA issue (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) but, as I've hinted, it would be  a pretty big change to the framework to scope all components that might be downstream of a scoped channel. But we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

That is a good explanation to why "Dispatcher has no subscribers" exception is encountered. We are going to employ Spring Integration in a multi-tenant environment so each tenant uses his/her own channels and service activators. We have applied the same scope to the service activator bean definition. Any suggestions to this?

```
<bean id="validSericeReference" class="ValidSericeClass" scope="validCustomScope"/>
```

Comment: Create a separate child context for each tenant (with channel, service) and use a dynamic router to route to the appropriate channel. See the dynamic FTP sample for an example of how to do that. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp

Comment: If your `ValidServiceClass` implements `MessageHandler` (perhaps a subclass of `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler`), you could subscribe a new one whenever you create a new channel - but your scope would have to do the work.

Comment: In my messaging context, there are a lot of channels and service handlers that are tenant specific, and I have to set scope for all of them. In this case, should I subscribe each message handler for each channel in my customer scope class? Any generic way that I can declare them in XML configuration?

Comment: Any suggestion to pollable channels in multi-tenant environment? Thanks.

Comment: You need dynamic runtime component wiring, regardless of the channel type. The framework assumes static wiring, established when the context is started.You might be able to do something with a custom namespace parser; the only solution with standard components I can think of is to use a dynamic router and put each tenant in its own child configuration.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. Child configuration for tenants looks a viable solution to me.